# blogging with markdown and latex

Tags: latex, frontend, syntax-highlighting, blogs

I love markdown, like those used by Github README.md and here on SO, especially how scripts can be render and highlighted according to language.

Being in academia, I also love latex for how it lets me produce great equations.

When I write my own blog (static pages on `github.io`), I can't find ways to reproduce features like

- latex equation rendering
- code snippet rendering with syntax highlight

Any pointer?

Comment: [org mode](https://orgmode.org) perhaps? It's not MD, but it's similar in being a fairly lightweight text-based markup (with a lot of other capabilities besides). Kaushal Modi's [ox-hugo](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/ox-hugo) export backend can produce [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/)-compatible markdown. See the ox-hugo page for some real-world examples.

Comment: How about [blogdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/) or [radix](https://rstudio.github.io/radix/)?